# How to convert list of lists into list -python

Tags: python, list

I need to convert a list of lists (containing strings) into a simple list of integers. 
I have

```
mylist = [["14"],["2"],["75"],["15"]]
```

I need

```
newlist = [14, 2, 75, 15]
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean a `set` of dictionaries? What you've mentioned in the "would need" section is a `set`, not a `dictionary`.

Comment: What are the keys of `dictofd`?

Comment: A dictionary requires a KEY and a VALUE. The one you show as dictofd is not a valid dictionary

Comment: Sorry, I realised the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension

```py
>>> mylist = [["14"],["2"],["75"],["15"]]                                 
>>> [int(item[0]) for item in mylist]
[14, 2, 75, 15]
```

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that this will only work if the sublists never have more than one item.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do two things with your list — flatten it out and then convert the strings to int. Flattening it is easy with `itertools.chain`. After that you can use `map()` to apply `int` to each item:

```
from itertools import chain

mylist = [["14"],["2"],["75"],["15"]]
newest = list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(mylist)))

# newest is => [14, 2, 75, 15]
```

This will work even if your lists have more than one item like: `[["14", "15"],["2"],["75"],["15"]]`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.ndarray.flatten(np.array([["14"],["2"],["75"],["15"]])).astype(int).tolist()
# Out[6]: [14, 2, 75, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary needs key and value pairs. That means a dictionary of Dictionaries has key and dictionary(as a value) pairs.

```py
dictofd = {{'name': 'jay', 'age': '78', ... }, {'name': 'kay', 'age': '32', ... },...}
```

This does not have keys. Therefore, you should use an array of dictionaries or set of dictionaries. If you have to use a dictionary, make some (artificial) keys like the below.

```py
dictofd = { 1: {'name': 'jay', 'age': '78', ... }, 2: {'name': 'kay', 'age': '32', ... }, ...}
```

Comment: Heads up: the OP edited the question to be completely different after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be,

```py
newlist = list(map(lambda sl: int(sl[0]), mylist))
```

You can use for loop as another approach.

```py
newlist = []
for sublist in mylist:
  newlist.append(int(sublist[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sublists might have more than one item, a nice list comprehention solution is:

```
newlist = [int(str) for sublist in mylist for str in sublist]
```

You can also refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/) article for more explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

This function works whatever the size of the lists:

```
from functools import reduce

my_list = [[1, 2], [10, 5], [-4, 5]]

reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, my_list)
```

Output: `[1, 2, 10, 5, -4, 5]`

Answer (score -1):

To achive this we have multiple ways to do,few examples are:

Using List Comprehension:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
flattened_list = [element for sublist in list_of_lists for element in sublist]
print(flattened_list)
```

Using itertools.chain:

import itertools

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
flattened_list = list(itertools.chain(*list_of_lists))
print(flattened_list)
```

Using sum() with List Comprehension:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
flattened_list = sum(list_of_lists, [])
print(flattened_list)
```

All these methods will produce the same output:

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```